# How do I get the string before the second last /

Tags: sql, regex, google-bigquery

I guess the answer to this question if somewhere but I wasn't able to find it.

so I have the basic following url `https://mywebsite.com/path1/path2/xxxx`

how can I extract `path2` with regex?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how can I extract path2 with regex?

Below quick example for BigQuery Standard SQL - one with regex and second w/o regex

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'https://mywebsite.com/path1/path2/xxxx' url
)
SELECT 
  REVERSE(SPLIT(REVERSE(url), '/')[SAFE_OFFSET(1)]) option1,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(url, r'(\w+)/\w+$') option2
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

with result

```
Row option1 option2  
1   path2   path2
```

Comment: I've tested the regex here regex101.com it doesn't work... where can I test it? Can you explain the regex? Thanks.

Comment: just run it in BigQuery UI. quick explanation - `\w+` any word, `$` end of string - `(\w+)` brackets identify which match to extract. Obviously if regex is not yet your "language" - that is exactly why I included non-regex option for you :o)